# Using angular pipe globally

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic project with angular, I need to use pipe for almost all my pages but I am getting errors:

## Logic

1. If I use `declarations` in one of my pages pipe works just fine
2. If I add same `declarations` in another page it returns error that
   this pipe has been used twice and I might consider using upper
   module.
3. If I add my pipe to `app.module.ts` file and try to access it in my pages it says pipe not found!

**Any idea how to get my pipe globally?**

## Code

`app.module.ts`

```
import { KeepHtmlPipe } from './pipes/keep-html.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, KeepHtmlPipe],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    VariationsPageModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    LaunchReview,
    NativeStorage,
    ImagePicker,
    Camera,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`pipe`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keepHtml'
})
export class KeepHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

`usage in html files`

```
<div [innerHTML]="product.stars | keepHtml"></div>
```

## Update

based on answers I've made new file `pipes.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { KeepHtmlPipe } from './keep-html.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        KeepHtmlPipe
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        KeepHtmlPipe
    ]
})
```

Then add it to my `app.module.ts`

```
import { PipesModule } from './pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    PipesModule, //here
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    VariationsPageModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    LaunchReview,
    NativeStorage,
    ImagePicker,
    Camera,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in my pages I add this:

```
import { KeepHtmlPipe } from 'src/app/pipes/keep-html.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [FavoritesPage, KeepHtmlPipe], //here
  exports: [
    KeepHtmlPipe //and here
  ]
})
export class FavoritesPageModule {}
```

Now I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type KeepHtmlPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: PipesModule and FavoritesPageModule! Please consider moving KeepHtmlPipe to a higher module that imports PipesModule and FavoritesPageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes KeepHtmlPipe then import that NgModule in PipesModule and FavoritesPageModule.
```

Comment: Add `PipesModule` to any modules where you're using the Pipe. Do not add it to the declarations, or exports for any module other than the `PipesModule`

Comment: @Jacquesジャック using it in import?

Comment: You only need to import the PipesModule in `app.module.ts` and all pipes will be available globally. You don't (and shouldn't) import the individual pipes again in your other modules. Just remove it completely from your `FavoritesPageModule `.

Comment: @Jacquesジャック I did remove it from my page and this time says `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'keepHtml' could not be found ("`

Comment: @mafortis I just posted an answer, hopefully it clears up any confusion.

Comment: @mafortis your code looks fine now. In case you the pipe is still not found and you're using `ionic serve` try quitting it and running it again.

Comment: @andypotato thank you for suggestion, i got it work not globally but able to access it in more than 1 page :) `for each page i have to import my shared module of pipes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting an answer to try and help explain some things.

As answered by others, you need to create a "shared" module of some kind. In your update, you've named it `PipesModule`, so I will use that from here on.

**Pipes Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { KeepHtmlPipe } from './keep-html.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        KeepHtmlPipe
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        KeepHtmlPipe
    ]
})
```

Now, when you *import this into any other module*, you will **automattically** have access to `KeepHtmlPipe`.

**FavoritesPageModule:**

```
import { PipesModule } from 'src/app/pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    PipesModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    FavoritesPage
  ]
})
export class FavoritesPageModule {}
```

Adding `PipesModule` to the imports here gives you access to the `KeepHtmlPipe` that was exported in the `PipesModule` in any component declared in this module (IE: Part of the `declarations` list).

**favorites-page.component.html**

`<div [innerHTML]="product.stars | keepHtml"></div>`

This should now work fine.

Comment: yes i just tried this and it works IF I remove it from my `app.module.ts` which means it allows me to have `KeepHtmlPipe` in more than 1 page but not globally because for each page i have to import this shared module. Anyhow it is working now not globally but working :) Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there is really anything that is truly available `globally` in the sense that you don't have to import it into the modules you're using it in. Specifically, if you're lazy loading modules, it wouldn't make sense to make stuff global as angular tries to separate out the modules so they don't all have to load at once.

Comment: i guess you're right, the important part was to be able to use it in more than 1 page and i can now, if i need to import it every time it doesn't matter that much :)

Comment: Right, I’d like to encourage you to upvote the other answers as their answers are correct, the explanation just wasn’t as good for your specific case.

Comment:  awesome, give that rep!

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is create a shared module, that your other modules can import. This was you can re-use components, pipes, module etc.. in any module!

You can do the following (you will have to remove `KeepHtmlPipe` from the current module)

```js
import { CommonModule } ...
import { NgModule } ...

import { KeepHtmlPipe } ...

// ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    KeepHtmlPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    KeepHtmlPipe
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

`!important` - you must export the `KeepHtmlPipe`

then in your app.module

```js
import { SharedModule } from ...

// ...

imports: [
   SharedModule
]
```

now you can use your pipe anywhere in your app, and in future if you want to add any more global pipes, directives or components they can go in this `SharedModule`

Comment: what's that shared module? sorry but i don't get it

Comment: @mafortis  You create it yourself, I've just called it SharedModule you can call it whatever you want like BananaModule. Its just a module that can be imported by other modules, which lets you import and export components, directives etc.. that can be used in multiple modules

Comment: @mafortis like I said in the above, you can only import your pipe `once` so remove it from `FavoritesPageModule`

Comment: I removed it now it says `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keepHtml' could not be found ("`

Comment: You will need to import the PipesModule into every module you wish to use it in, not just your app module

Comment: So you will also need to import it in your `FavouritePagesModule` if you plan on using it there - you can import your PipesModule into as many modules as you like

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to create a module containing all your global pipes, then import the module in your app module. Here's how you do it:

1) Create pipes.module.ts inside src/pipes folder

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { KeepHtmlPipe } from './keep-html.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      KeepHtmlPipe
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
      KeepHtmlPipe
    ]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

2) In your app.module import the PipesModule and add it to the `imports` collection

```
import { PipesModule } from '../pipes/pipes.module';

[...]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    [...]
    PipesModule
  ],
[...]
```

Afterwards you can use your pipe anywhere in the app. If you add more global pipes later just also add it to your PipesModule.

Comment: do i need to add anything else in my pages modules as well?